# Subdomain or New domain for new company division - SEO

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain

Someone has asked me about developing a site for a new division that this company is expanding to include in their services.  They have purchased a domain for this new service, but I was wondering:

Since they already have an established domain with a Pagerank (3), would they be better suited with a subdomain (specialty.domain.com), redirected to from their new domain?  Any SEO benefit here?

Comment: There are quite a few questions revolving around this topic here. I suggest using the search feature, or Google, to read up on them and learn more about subdomain vs new domain questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with redirecting a domain to a sub-domain that are often forgotten. One is the sub-domain will, at some point, have to stand on it's own. Often, if a domain is redirected to another, the question comes up regarding deleting the original domain. Any links, trust score, site score is passed using a 301 redirect, however, if the desire comes about to delete the original domain, then these things are lost. Using a redirect is not a bad solution, it often ends up being a temporary solution and the new domain or sub-domain must stand on it's own. It becomes imperative that the new domain or sub-domain gain links, a trust score, and site score on it's own.

If the existing domain is performing well, it should be a consideration if it still makes sense to keep the domain. A decision should be made in advance. It is fine to redirect to a sub-domain, you will suffer a small loss with any 301 redirect, but it may be wise to continue to with the original domain name if it makes sense. That is a business decision regarding branding and company identity. If the company decides that a sub-domain is best, then prepare yourself to work on the sub-domains standing for the inevitable day where the company will want to delete the original domain.